# Scalability of a php application

Tags: php, performance, cakephp, scalability

I built my application using cakephp. It works fine. My application still in beta with 3000 beta users(invites based). I am want to expand it for bigger end user base.

Few things about my app.

1) I am using mysql database table has around ~ 25000 records.
2) Multiple models and many multiple hasMany and belongsTo and HABTM relationships

First Question.
1) How I can I improve my site performance.
2) What is result limit from queries on the database(10s). 
4) Should I move application to newer technology or framework.

The number of records and relationships are growing.

I started app in cakephp less than three months back with little (MVC) knowledge. It is amazing easy to build and test applications. I would recommend it to friends anyday.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Use [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/).

Comment: 25k records is a fairly small database, but if you are have **measurable** performance problems (and aren't simply worrying over the possibilities) look to optimise your SQL queries and ensure that you have appropriate indexes.

Comment: @sexyprout that's some bad advice, unless you're suggesting it sarcastically.  First, Josh should determine where his bottleneck is.  If he has his tables indexed properly, I highly doubt his DB is the bottleneck at the moment.  Especially using Cake.  And even if the db were the bottleneck, it's a little bandwagon-y and fanboy-ish to just say "use MongoDB".

Comment: @Travis Why are you so close-minded?

Comment: @sexyprout, what specific problems mentioned by OP do MongoDB solve better and in what way? Other than being the "secret ingredient in web-scale sauce"?

Comment: @sexyprout I use Mongo, so I'm not close minded against it.  I was objecting to your glib response, as if Mongo will solve all his problems.  In this situation, CakePHP is his bottleneck, not the data storage layer.  Your response added nothing to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search resulted in the following sites, all dedicated to speeding CakePHP up considerably.  In addition, here are my thoughts on Cake's speed:

1. Make sure you're using the latest Cake release.  The update from Cake 1.2 to 1.3 yielded about a 20% speed boost for my biggest app.
2. Make sure you have caching turned on (for most read-intense applications, this will help massively).
3. If you have a LOT of models that are related, but infrequently used, try loading those models lazily.

Remember that Cake isn't really built for speed.  The other answers here are good for generic situations, but with CakePHP, the bottleneck is usually with the web layer.  So one (fairly simple) way to scale out is to load your pages through a proxy server that passes requests to a backend processing farm.

Also, I highly recommend that you profile your code.  This means using an IDE like Zend, where you can insert breakpoints to determine the slow sections of your code.  At a minimum, install the Cake debug toolbar, which will show you execution times for major sections of your app (request handler loading, controller execution, view render time, etc.)

Results for google search on "optimizing CakePHP for speed":

- Good CakePHP specific tips:
  http://www.endyourif.com/optimizing-cakephp-websites/
- Lazy Load models:
  http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Frank/2010/08/10/optimizing-model-loading-with-lazymodel
- More Cake Tips:
  http://www.pseudocoder.com/archives/2009/03/17/8-ways-to-speed-up-cakephp-apps/

Comment: I was worried If my site could handle extra traffic and would not leave end users frustrated waiting for a page to load. Thanks for your feedback I will sure look into it.

Comment: I would recommend that you use a system monitoring tool, as well as a load testing tool, so that you know what your app's limits are.  The load testing is done in advance, so you can say, "we can support N users with this setup, while keeping response times under 2s".  The monitoring service will help you model your resource usage.  Combine the two and you can effectively predict the point when your server load will spike and response times increase.

Answer (score 5):

> How I can I improve my site performance?

Hard to say without knowing where the bottleneck is. One approach would be to:

1. Start by optimising your SQL queries, enable slow query logging and examine them, properly index columns, and change SQL server's configuration if needed.
2. [Profile](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) PHP execution, analyse report and make sure to refactor the code where needed.
3. Introduce caching, flat files, SQL caching, [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php), [Memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) etc. (just don't use all of them together :)
4. Optimize server configuration, including software and hardware.
5. Move to several servers.

> What is result limit from queries on the database(10s)?

You mean execution time? As fast as possible :) But then again, depends on the query itself. If the query is executed once every day, it can be slower than if it is executed with every request. Time depends on first question/answer above.

> Should I move application to newer technology or framework?

This one is hard to answer. Again, depends on what the problems are and whether you can identify and fix them. If you can solve them by optimizing queries and database, caching etc., then the problem is not in the framework. I strongly advise to think about it thoroughly before switching to another technology or rewriting the code.

Comment: Excellent tips, for general app performance improvement.  Using Cake as much as I do, I think the bottleneck here is going to be in the PHP/Cake layer (cake is slooooooow).  There are a few easy tips WRT cake that will speed up your app by up to 100%.